# Differences between имя, имён and имена?

Tags: значения

Could you please answer with samples which are clear and easy to comprehend for a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are all forms of the same word, "имя" (name).

Имя -- nominative case singular. Пример: "Моё имя -- Исмаил".

Имена -- nom. case plural, пример: "Назовите ваши имена!"

Имён -- genitive case plural, пример: "Никто не знает их имён".

Comment: thank you for fast reply, I try to read a book in Russian about grammar, in book written "-имена существительные- в имненительном падеже", translator says "nouns" for "имена существительные" but there are two words there, that made me confused and I searched about meanings of these two words and than I'm totally confused and it leaded me here. I know it should be one another question but could you please translate it exactly word by word in a way which makes little bit sense.

Comment: "имена существительные"  (or, in singular, "имя существительное") is a fixed term, which means "nouns" (respectively, "noun"). Similarly, the term "имя прилагательное" means "adjective".

Comment: you really do it good by giving nominated forms of words and it helps me a lot, because there are also many cases in my native language. But i didn't quite get your comments well, the problem is uncle google says существительное is the word noun in English and имя is the the word noun in English too, so it's like "noun noun" which doesn't make sense, so there should be a difference, I know it's a term just like "имя прилагательное" in your example, gosh maybe I should stop paying that much attention about these details, but for learning deeply it's needed..

Comment: "существительное" is a reduced form of the full term "имя существительное". Translated literally it might go something like "the name of an existing thing".

Comment: thanks a lot for your concern and help, it's more clear now.

Comment: @Ismail Yilmaz имя существительное = substantive noun, имя прилагательное = adjective noun.